# Where did JDK location in Android Studio 2020.3.1 (Canary 14) goes?

Tags: android, android-studio

In Android Studio 4.1.3, we can see the JDK location in the SDK location setting page, as shown below

[image]

However in Android Studio 2020.3.1 (Canary 14), the JDK location no longer visible? Has it gone somewhere else, or it is using the JAVA_HOME setting JDK by default?

[image]

Note, both having an Android Project opened. Hence it is not because no project is opened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The setting to configure the JDK used by Gradle moved over here:
[image: Android Studio Gradle JDK]

Comment: This entry is also gone for me.

Comment: @Kuno mine too. There is no such entry in Gradle section